# Flutter Windows pass list of String/dynamic to MethodChannel

Tags: flutter, windows, list, dart, channel

According to official [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-c-plus-plus-tab) you have to use std::vector to pass a list for Windows MethodChannel, however, it does not specify the allowed types.

If you try to pass a list of string and read them as std::vectorstd::string app will crash. How to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually dart passes std::vector of type EncodableValue like this std::vector, to read values from it you need to loop through this list and call one more std::get on each value.

[image]